# LaunchDarkly React SDK - How Do I Disable Console Logs?

Tags: launchdarkly

I am currently using the LaunchDarkly React SDK.  I see the below on every page of my app:

[image]

How do I disable these console logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talked to LD support and you could set `LDLogLevel` to `none`, ie `LDLogLevel: none`